# How to sort characters in string but keeping only apostrophe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out how to sort characters in string but keeping apostrophe.
This is what I've done so far:

```
def scramble_word(word) -> str:
    index = word.find("'")
    return word[0] + ''.join(sorted(word[1:index]+word[index+1:-1], key=str.lower)) + word[-1]


print(scramble_word("Mo'uSE"))  # -> Mo'SuE
print(scramble_word("qu'iz"))  # -> qi'uz
```

What I get is MoSue and qiuz. How to insert apostrophe back to string?

Comment: What should happen if there's more than one apostrophe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def scramble_word(word, keep="'"):
    """Return a scrambled word by sorting middle letters; `keep` character if found."""
    apos_idx = word.find(keep)
    word = word.replace(keep, "")
    shuffled = [word[0]] + sorted(word[1:-1], key=str.lower) + [word[-1]]
    if apos_idx != -1: 
        shuffled.insert(apos_idx, keep)
    return "".join(shuffled)
```

**Demo**

```
words = ["Mo'uSE", "qu'iz", "normal"]
for word in words:
    print(scramble_word(word))

# Mo'SuE
# qi'uz
# namorl
```

---

A more general solution that preserves all punctuation:

```
import string


def scramble_word(word):
    """Return a word by sorting middle letters; preserve punctuation."""
    puncts = [(word.find(c), c) for c in word if c in string.punctuation and word.find(c) > 0]
    replaced = [c for c in word if c not in {i[-1] for i in puncts}]
    shuffled = [replaced[0]] + sorted(replaced[1:-1], key=str.lower) + [replaced[-1]]
    [shuffled.insert(pos, p) for pos, p in puncts]
    return "".join(shuffled)

words = ["Mo'uSE", "qu'iz", "normal", "P-u.n*c(t!u;a:tio>n"]
for word in words:
    print(scramble_word(word))

# Mo'SuE
# qi'uz
# namorl
# P-a.c*i(n!o;t:tuu>n
```

This is done by collecting all (position, punctuation) pairs in each word, removing them, performing the scrambling algorithm and finally reinserting the punctuation.

Comment: But why sorting of all punctuation positions should be done? Why just not remove them and after scrambling put them back?

Comment: The former implementation iterated over `string.punctuation`.  Sorting by position was used to maintain the order of punctuation in the string, e.g. [(1, '-'), (3, '.'), (5, '*'), ...`, which is needed later when reinserting the punctuation after shuffling letters.  However, the last update fixes this using a new list comprehension that iterates the `word`.  See edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `"'"` again to the string, not the perfect way but works for current scenario.

```
def scramble_word(word) -> str:
    index = word.find("'")
    stra = word[0] + ''.join(sorted(word[1:index] + word[index+1:-1], key=str.lower)) + word[-1]
    return stra[:index] + "'" + stra[index:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def scramble_word(word) -> str:
    index = word.find("'")
    str = ''.join(sorted(word[0:index] + word[index+1:]))
    return str[:index] + "'" + str[index:]

print(scramble_word("Mo'uSE"))  # -> EM'Sou
print(scramble_word("qu'iz"))  # -> iq'uz
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might help:

```
>>> def scramble_word(word) -> str:
    index = word.find("'")
    sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(word, key=str.lower)).replace("'", "")
    return sorted_word[:index] + "'" + sorted_word[index:]

>>> scramble_word("Mo'uSE")
"EM'Sou"
>>> print(scramble_word("qu'iz"))
iq'uz
>>>
```